# Which car was Tony Stark driving in the end of Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie, Tony Stark was seen driving an orange luxury car. It looked like Lamborghini, but it wasn't really Lamborghini (I am very much familiar with lots of Lamborghinis). I tried to look for the brand logo, but without luck.

Which car was that Tony Stark driving?

Comment: “I am very much familiar with lots of Lamborghinis” — me too bro, jus the way I roll yo.

Comment: This may be poorly phrased but it is a question with a factual answer, probably doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: It's just a boring Audi ....... but it's well worth remembering Audi indeed own Lamborghini these days!  That's why Lamborghini today actually run without breaking down every minute - making the world much better for very rich folks everywhere!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Audi’s newest R8 in 'Avengers: Age of Ultron'

**From Marvel's press release:**

> Tony continues to redesign and evolve his classic armor, just like Audi improved its R8 for 2016. In Marvel’s “Avengers: Age of Ultron,” Tony’s newest **[Audi R8](http://www.carmagazine.co.uk/spy-shots/audi/audi-r8-2015-first-spy-shots-of-audis-new-supercar/)** features a 5.2-litre-V10 engine, ceramic brakes with brake discs made of carbon fibre-reinforced-ceramics, and quattro® permanent all-wheel drive, proving Tony’s taste are as superior as his vehicular decisions!

[image]

- Audi continues partnership with Marvel Entertainment for May 1 release of Marvel’s Avengers: Age of Ultron
- Featured models include the all-new 2016 R8, 2015 TTS and 2015 A3 Cabriolet

#### [Production Notes:](http://www.motorauthority.com/news/1097818_addition-of-new-r8-in-avengers-age-of-ultron-will-be-done-with-cgi-video)

> We recently told you that a fleet of new Audis, including the all-new R8 supercar, will appear in the upcoming movie Avengers: Age of Ultron. What we didn’t know at the time was that the R8 used for filming was actually the previous-generation model and not the new one that made its debut last month at the 2015 Geneva Motor Show.
>
> To ensure they have the latest version of the R8 for the movie, however, the development team will use computer wizardry to make the previous model look like the new one, reveals executive producer Jeremy Latcham in the video above. That shouldn’t be much of a problem for the team as one of the movie’s main characters, the Hulk, is pretty much completely rendered using CGI.

Comment: Mmmmm, smell the product placement. *SMELL IT*

Comment: “Tony continues to redesign and evolve his classic armor, just like Audi improved its R8 for 2016.” Imagine someone who would have their car-purchase decisions influenced by a sentence like this. Then imagine them on the road. Jesus Christ.

Comment: As a former Audi owner (A6, not S8), I can say that I've spoken with people who have their purchase decisions influenced in this way. It's a sad thing.